# WKWebView WebGL performance is lower than Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, webgl, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm trying to show [this stream](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg-vnc) in my app using WKWebView, but the frame rate is less than 1 FPS. Stream is using webGL. When I open the same stream in Safari, it works beautifully. I'm planning to use [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/index.html) and insert it as subview into my view. Is that possible? Do you think the performance will be better? Can my app get rejected because of doing so? Can editing client JavaScript improve performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kept searching and I knew, that there must be somewhere some acceleration in WebView Config. Just allow inline media playback and enjoy speed.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebViewConfiguration_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/WKWebViewConfiguration

Comment: I have this set to true and my game is still twice as slow as native safari